# Espresso- lines in the text view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I am trying to get a number of lines, in Espresso, of the TextView from one of the elements from recycler view. This is my macher for it:

```
 public static TypeSafeMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> isTextInLines(final int lines) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
            Log.e("Lines", ((TextView) item.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTextView)).getLineCount() + "");
            return ((TextView) item.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTextView)).getLineCount() == lines;
        }


        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("isTextInLines");
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that it prints that all of them has 0 lines. As I understand the problem might be that it is still in drawing phase according to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/6470918

Any idea how to solve it?

PS. This is the code which uses this matcher:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .perform(scrollToHolder(isTextInLines(12)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any `RecyclerViewAction::scrollTo...`  binds all adapter items to the in memory `ViewHolder`s and loops over those to find the adapter position of the item that you are interested in and then scrolls to that position. And because of this, these `ViewHolder`s are never laid out.

Unfortunately, to get the number of lines of the TextView it has to be laid out first.

You can work your problem around with normal `ViewAssertion` like so `onView(matcher).check(matches(isTextInLines(12))` or even `onView(isTextInLines(12)).check(matches(isDisplayed())`

You might need to scroll to the ViewHolder using other matchers that don't require layout pass first, in case the ViewHolder is off the screen.